# Writing Treetop rule to parse input in any order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, treetop

I'm looking for a way to write Treetop rules which will find some values in any order. So:

```
rule top
  # ?
end    

rule gender
  ('women'/'men') / ''
end

rule age_under
  ('under' age) / ''
end

rule age
  [0-9]+
end
```

I would like to parse these inputs:

```
"women under 10"
"under 10 women"
"under 10"
"women"
```

How can I achieve this ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of parsing in any order. The only trouble is you would have to handle duplicates by hand since Treetop doesn't have a rule for unordered-non-repeating elements.

```
rule top
 ((gender / age_under) ' '?)*
end

rule gender
 'women' / 'men'
end

rule age_under
 'under ' age
end

rule age
 [0-9]+
end
```

Comment: That's incredible how poorly Treetop is documented taking into consideration how good this library is.

Comment: Yeah, it is pretty poor. Did you see the [homepage](http://cjheath.github.io/treetop/)? [Here](http://po-ru.com/diary/getting-started-with-treetop/) is a quick tutorial as well.